# How to load XML in javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml

I have the following code which I suppose to call an XML file but I receive the following error `GET http://tdhdemo.com/generator/data/xml/ 403 (Forbidden)`

Can anyone explain to me where am I wrong as I really can't figure out?

this is the code that I am using:

```
var dataPath = "data/";
var xmlPath = "data/xml/";
var canvasObject = '';
var canvas = {
        width: 0,
        height: 0
    };
var data = {
        width: 0,
        height: 0,
        date: 0,
        place: 0,
        city: 0,
        country: "ro",
        countries: {}
    };
function startUp(){
        canvasObject = document.getElementById("generatorCanvas");
        resetCanvas();
        loadCountries();
        formEvents();
    }
function loadCountries(){
        $.get(dataPath+'countries.json', function(data) {
            data.countries = data;
            addCountriesToSelect();
        });
    }
function addCountriesToSelect(){
        $.each(data.countries, function(index, val) {
             $('[name=country]').append('<option value="'+index+'">'+val.name+'</option>');
        });
    }
function resetCanvas(){
        makeLogo();

        width = data.width;
        height = $("#generatorLogo").height() / 100 * 65;

        canvasObject.width = width;
        canvasObject.height = height;
        canvasContext = canvasObject.getContext("2d");

        canvasContext.fillStyle = "#cd2026";
        canvasContext.fillRect(0,0,width,height);

        canvasContext.font="20px HMAmpersand";
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like your url is wrong and you're asking for directory rather than file so the server does not allow it. So not an "XML problem" just plain getting the page. Try putting the URL in browser and make sure you have URL which you can actually bring up.

Comment: Are you hosting your code somewhere on tdhdemo.com? If not, then it will understandably fail with a cross-origin access exception.

Comment: it is hosted on tdhdemo.com the problem is that before everything was wrapped in a `var generator = {..}` and function were looking like this `loadCountries: function() {..}, addCountriesToSelect: function() {..},` and what I've tried was to create normal view of functions as in the example. Then I received this

Answer (score 0):

Check your xml endpoint.  There is some data manipulation code here, but just getting to read an XML from server can be done using this code (using jQuery)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "data.xml",
   dataType: "xml",
   success: function(xmlData) {
    //manipulate XML data here

   }
 });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you can load javascript like this this code from from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_intro.asp)

```
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xhttp);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "books.xml", true);
    xhttp.send();
function myFunction(xml) {
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
```